# Oracle 12c release 1 Histograms for skewed data

Tags: oracle, histogram, table-statistics

We are running Oracle Applications 12.2.4 on a 12.1.0.2.0 database. When I do the following query:

```
select DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('AUTOSTATS_TARGET') as autostats_target,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('CASCADE') as cascade,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('DEGREE') as degree,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('ESTIMATE_PERCENT') as estimate_percent,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('METHOD_OPT') as method_opt,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('NO_INVALIDATE') as no_invalidate,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('GRANULARITY') as granularity,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('PUBLISH') as publish,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('INCREMENTAL') as incremental,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('STALE_PERCENT') as stale_percent
from   dual
```

I get:

```
"AUTOSTATS_TARGET","CASCADE","DEGREE","ESTIMATE_PERCENT","METHOD_OPT","NO_INVALIDATE","GRANULARITY","PUBLISH","INCREMENTAL","STALE_PERCENT"
"AUTO","DBMS_STATS.AUTO_CASCADE","NULL","DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE","FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO","DBMS_STATS.AUTO_INVALIDATE","AUTO","TRUE","FALSE","10"
```

However when I run:

```
select distinct histogram
from   user_tab_col_statistics
```

I only get `NONE`

How is it possible that an Oracle Application instance can have no tables with skews that need histograms? Or am I not understanding the settings?

Also when you want a histogram on a column do you have to use `method_opt => 'for all columns size skewonly'`? How can you specify auto for all columns and skew for one column?

I would really like the potential huge speed increase that histograms can bring and I am surprised that Oracle Applications does not provide this by default. There is a Gather Schema Statistics process that runs every night, could it be that the code in that is very old and that it kills any dbms_stats calls? I specifically created the following index which should have a histogram.

```
create index xxpqh_ss_trans_history_idx1 on hr.pqh_ss_transaction_history (process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1)) compress 1 tablespace apps_ts_tx_idx;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'HR', tabname => 'PQH_SS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY', cascade => true, method_opt => 'for all columns size skewonly');
```

Comment: My knwoledge in hostigram is little , but when run a query on table with indexed column, the optimizer will specify its method. for more info i really recommand to read this post from oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_histo.htm#TGSQL368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Applications uses its *own* mechanisms for statistics collection and you should be using dbms_stats directly.

*"Oracle E-Business Suite statistics should only be gathered using FND_STATS or the Gather Statistics concurrent request. Gathering statistics with DBMS_STATS or the desupported ANALYZE command may result in suboptimal executions plans for E-Business Suite"*

Please refer to the following whitepaper for recommendations:

Best Practices for Gathering Statistics with Oracle E-Business Suite (MOS Note 1586374.1)

Comment: How can not using any histograms lead to optimal execution plans?

Comment: I didn't say that :-) I said you need to use the mechanism that is part of Applications, not your own DBMS_STATS calls.

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing. Should I set the Gather Options parameter of Gather Schema Statistics to GATHER AUTO or GATHER? That is which part controls AUTO SAMPLE SIZE

Comment: Also how does one enable table monitoring which it says is needed for GATHER AUTO?

Comment: Table monitoring is automatically on.  No need to run anything to activate it.

Comment: This document was not helpful. When I run fnd_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'HR', tabname => 'PQH_SS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY', cascade => true
--, method_opt => 'for all columns size skewonly'
); then there is no option for specifying skewonly, but even without it nothing is produced in user_tab_statistics

Comment: And you ran "LOAD_HISTOGRAM_COLS" as per the document? If so, and you did not get them, then its time to call Support.

Comment: LOAD_HISTOGRAM_COLS fixed it. There doesn't seem to be any indication of whether it's used HYBRID or TOP-FREQUENCY though.

Comment: check USER_TAB_COLS.HISTOGRAM

Comment: USER_TAB_COLS returns no rows for table_name = 'PQH_SS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY'

Comment: Try ALL_TAB_COLS.  USER = stuff you own, ALL = stuff you have access to, DBA = the lot, CDB = well, lets not go there

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!